# SQL: Counting and grouping rows

Tags: mysql, sql, count

```
id | userid | exerciseid | date                | time | weight | distance | reps
1  | 24     | 1          | 2013-09-28 00:00:00 | 2321 | 231    | 121      | NULL
2  | 24     | 24         | 2013-09-28 00:00:00 | 2321 | 231    | 121      | NULL
3  | 24     | 1          | 2013-09-28 00:00:00 | 2321 | 231    | 121      | NULL
4  | 24     | 1          | 2000-00-00 00:00:00 | NULL | 100    | NULL     | 2
5  | 24     | 1          | 2013-09-28 00:00:00 | 2321 | 231    | 121      | NULL
```

Rows 1, 3, and 5 are the same. I want to do a count that groups them together, whilst also adding a column with the count value.

```
SELECT id, userid, exerciseid, date, time, weight, distance, reps    
FROM `exercises`
WHERE `userid` = 1 AND `date` < now()
```

So I want this to return something similar too:

```
id | userid | exerciseid | date                | time | weight | distance | reps | count
1  | 24     | 1          | 2013-09-28 00:00:00 | 2321 | 231    | 121      | NULL | 3
4  | 24     | 1          | 2000-00-00 00:00:00 | NULL | 100    | NULL     | 2    | NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT id, userid, exerciseid, date, time, weight, distance, reps,
       count(*) as count
FROM `exercises`
WHERE userid = 1 AND date < now()
GROUP BY id, userid, exerciseid, date, time, weight, distance, reps
```

Comment: Is it possible to have the count column be NULL if 1?

Comment: you can replace count( * ) with IF (COUNT( * ) = 1, NULL, COUNT( * )) AS count

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT Count(*) As CountM, id, userid, exerciseid, date, time, weight, distance, reps    
FROM `exercises`
WHERE `userid` = 1 AND `date` < now()
Group by id, userid, exerciseid, date, time, weight, distance, reps
```